# how to add or subtract quantity from 2 different tables based on a third table?

Tags: sql-server

First of all I want to say sorry if I say or do something wrong because this is my firs time that I ask something. I'm new to sql server so I tried do find out myself but I didn't find something that may help me so this is why I'm here. I have 3 different tables:

```
1.tbl_Product with ID, Quantity and others;
2.tbl_Type with ID, Name;
3.tbl_Entry_Exit with ID,TypeID,ProductID,Quantity,Price,Total.
```

I want to add or subtract the quantity from `tbl_Product` if `TypeID = 1(Entry) or 2(Subtract) from tbl_Entry_Exit`.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you actually want to update tbl_Product and store the value permanently or are you simply wanting to return this result in a query (without modifying the underlying data)?

Comment: Yes I would like to permanently update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TP
   SET TP.Quantity = TP.Quantity+ TE.Quantity 
  FROM tbl_Product  TP inner join tbl_Entry_Exit TE
    on TP.ID=TE.ProductID 
 WHERE TE.TypeID=1

UPDATE TP
   SET TP.Quantity = TP.Quantity- TE.Quantity 
  FROM tbl_Product  TP inner join tbl_Entry_Exit TE
    on TP.ID=TE.ProductID 
 WHERE TE.TypeID=2
```

Hope This work or some modification will be needed...

Comment: You can like :)

Comment: But, if I may ask Do you know if it is posibile to automatically update this database from the application? I have a mvc application that needs to do this automatically. Any advice is really apriciated.

Comment: Yes when you doing entry into the tbl_Entry_Exit at that time only you can update the tbl_Product depending on the TypeId you can add quantity or subtract quantity.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the correct outcome the op wants but the below query would serve some purpose -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN E.TypeID = 1 THEN (P.Quantity + E.Quantity)
                WHEN E.TypeID = 2 THEN (P.Quantity - E.Quantity)                           
           END AS DerivedQuantity 
    FROM tbl_Product P INNER JOIN tbl_Entry_Exit E
    ON P.ID = E.ID
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't do the right thing. but thank you anyway!